# TGA color mapped color convert to RGB or RGBA

Tags: c++, image, parsing, format, tga

I'm writing a tga parser in C++ for fun and now it can read files of imagetypes 2, 3, 10, but I'm stuck at type 1 where they have color map. I don't know how to convert color mapped colors to rgb or rgba. It seems like for an type 1 image (unencoded), if I have a `char* color_map`, I should turn it to `uint_8*` and if the `color_map_entry_depth` is 24 and `pixel_depth` is 8 and we have a `uint8_t pixel_data[3]` taken from the file buffer, the first pixel color will be

```
RGB(color_map[pixel_data[2]],color_map[pixel_data[1],color_map[pixel_data[0]])
```

But it gives me wrong color. Could anybody help?

Comment: You might take a look through this TGA reader for help. https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h and search for `stbi__tga_load`. You need to read 1 byte and use that to index into the 3 entries for RGB in the palette. It looks like you're reading 3 bytes of data and trying to use that to index the palette for one pixel.

Comment: but how to access to 3 colors using color_map[pixel_data] if pixel_data is one uint_8? do i need to mask the result?

Comment: Each entry in the palette is 3 bytes, so R = colormap[pixel_data * 3 + 0], G = colormap[pixel_data * 3 + 1], B = colormap[pixel_data * 3 + 2]. At least I assume the palette entries are RGB, haven't manually read a TGA in a while. If they are in a different order adjust the offset as necessary. Looking at the stb source I linked before it's possible they are BGR. *shrug* Use the right test image and it'll be pretty obvious.